# How to trim results from a substring-with-regex match?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have this set of data in postgresql:

```
en_MY_V2_CID_MY_SEM_1_1_0_0
en_MY_V2_CID_MY_SEM_2_101_1703_0
en_MY_V2_CID_MY_SEM_2_101_1724_0
en_MY_CID_MY_DIS_1_100_1705_0068
en_MY_CID_MY_DIS_1_100_1705_0068
```

I want to extract the substring like these:

```
en_MY_V2_CID_MY_SEM_1
en_MY_V2_CID_MY_SEM_2
en_MY_V2_CID_MY_SEM_2
en_MY_CID_MY_DIS_1
en_MY_CID_MY_DIS_1
```

Problem is, the left-side structure is not constant so I can't grasp them using regex. Instead, the right-side structure *is* constant, with the format `_numbers_numbers_numbers_numbers`. So I try to do use this query in postgresql:

```
select substring(name from '_\d+_\d+_\d+$') from logs;
```

And get:

```
1_0_0
101_1703_0
101_1724_0
100_1705_0068
1705_0068
```

So the question is, how do I negate, or trim the previous substring so I will get my results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rexep_replace

```
select regexp_replace(name,E'\(\\w\)_\\d+_\\d+_\\d+$',E'\\1') from logs;
```

Comment: or simpler still: `select regexp_replace(name,E'_\\d+_\\d+_\\d+$', '') from logs;`